# Android Simplest and Clossest component to make a TimeTable

Tags: android, layout, components

what's the closes and the simplest component to do something like this [image]

and some tips pls

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking from the UI point of view you might consider nesting something inside a [GridLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridLayout.html)